# Find a pattern of binary numbers using shift-right and bitwise-AND?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

I'm attempting to write a function in assembly that will detect if a longer binary number contains a smaller binary pattern.

Example:
Does **100111** contain **1001**?

When I read this problem I figured that I would do a bitwise-AND with the large number and its smaller pattern while shifting right (logical) each time in a loop.

So, in my head I thought it would do:

```
100111 AND 1001 = 0  
Shift-right 1  
010011 AND 1001 = 0  
Shift-right 1  
001001 AND 1001 = 1 // Pattern FOUND!
```

and repeat this until either the number was shifted until it was zero or the AND returned 1.

However, I think I must have something confused because this is returning 1 for most things I put in, on the first run of the loop.  Am I confused on my usage of AND?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that "partial matches" also return a non-zero value for your AND check:

```
100111 AND 001001 = 000001
```

So this tests if *any* of the bits match, but you want to make sure *all* bits are the same. The result of the AND needs to be equal to the pattern you are searching:

```
x = 100111
if (x AND 1001 == 1001)
  print "found"
```

Comment: Note that `x & mask == mask` checks that all the set-bit in `mask` are set, but it **ignores any cleared bits**.  In this case, it would mean that you find `1001` in `11111111` (at every possible position).  If that's not what you want, `x & 0b1111 == pattern` is the normal way.  (See Marko's and Deadcode's answers.)

Answer (score 1):

You should AND and then test against the search pattern:

```
if ((TestPattern & SearchPattern) == SearchPattern)
{
   // then match
}
```

(where `&` represents bitwise `AND`)

Comment: I'm using the MIPS "And" instruction, which is Bitwise.

Comment: AHhh, I see.  I wasn't doing the equality test back against the search pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise AND does not work the way you expect (judging from the samples and ignoring the notation which seems to suggest you are using bitwise AND as the logical AND of bits). AND only takes the bits that are set to 1 "into account". E.g 1111 AND 1001 == 1001.

You need to use XOR and compare against 0 for match (remember the mask the bits you are not comparing from the result). In your example a match is found when (N ^ 1001) & 1111 == 0000

Comment: This is also equivalent to `N & 1111 == pattern`.  Your way might be useful in assembly language, for example many have a `test` instruction that sets flags according to a bitwise AND, so you could `xor eax, pattern` / `test al, 0xf` / `jz all_selected_bits_matched`.  But that's still destructive of the low bits, so usually just as easy to copy / and and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure that both the 0 and 1 bits match your search pattern, you need to do something like this:

```
if ((InputPattern AND SearchMask) == SearchPattern)
{
    // then match
}
```

The `SearchMask` should be all 1 bits, of a length equal to your SearchPattern. For example, you could have `SearchMask == 1111, SearchPattern == 1001`.